# Are questions about browser plugins acceptable?

Tags: discussion, scope

I feel the answer is YES, asking for confidence and Meta completeness.

Comment: The question is: Why not? Yes, plugins are on-topic.

Just because these software pieces aren't stand-alone products, doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes they should be acceptable.

We accept [questions about plugins](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=plugin) into other software as well, so browsers are no different.