# Is asking for an extension on any browser too broad?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

I know asking for a browser extension (extension/add-on/plugin/etc.) [is acceptable](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/133); however, I was wondering if a question would be considered too broad if it is asking for an extension on *any* browser. Should we require users to select one browser or at least give a list of browsers they would find acceptable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don’t think that such a question would be *necessarily* too broad.

Deciding if it’s too broad would depend on the given requirements, so there’s really no difference between questions restricting it to one browser and questions accepting answers for multiple or even all browsers.

If no operating system requirement is given, and if OP doesn’t explicitly state that all OS are acceptable, it would make sense to ask in the comments if that’s really intended (and if yes, the question should be edited to mention this). This way we can prevent misunderstandings in case OP simply forgot to mention their operating system(s). ¹

I dig through our [web-browser](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-browser) questions. Here are some looking for a browser extension without mentioning which browsers are acceptable (we have many more questions that accept solutions for all browsers, but still state what’s preferred):

- [Keeping track (count) of the videos I've watched in YouTube](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1920/keeping-track-count-of-the-videos-ive-watched-in-youtube)
- [Browser plugin to suggest words as you type](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3759/browser-plugin-to-suggest-words-as-you-type)
- [Browser plugin to capture markup / DOM](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7290/browser-plugin-to-capture-markup-dom)
- [Adblocker that still helps the sites I visit?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11624/adblocker-that-still-helps-the-sites-i-visit)
- [Browser with extensive caching options or add-on](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10919/browser-with-extensive-caching-options-or-add-on)
- [Browser extensions to custom enhance text information, alternative to "Find in page"](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16286/browser-extensions-to-custom-enhance-text-information-alternative-to-find-in-p)
- [Browser extension to automatically cache all links](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16472/browser-extension-to-automatically-cache-all-links)
- [Browser plugin to fill in form fields based on the id or name attribute matched against a regular expression?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23517/browser-plugin-to-fill-in-form-fields-based-on-the-id-or-name-attribute-matched)
- [Are there any plugins for browser for changing website colors?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21217/are-there-any-plugins-for-browser-for-changing-website-colors)

I don’t consider any of these to be too broad.

(¹ This is an example where I suspect that OP has some restrictions which browser/OS would be acceptable, but OP unfortunately never provided more details: [Browser plugin to prevent HTML5 videos from autoplaying](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16753/browser-plugin-to-prevent-html5-videos-from-autoplaying))